# OpenIddict how to create a client with multiple secrets

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

Is there anyway to create a client in OpenIddict which has multiple secrets.

I was trying to create a client/application and I can only create a secret for that client. I would like to create multiple secrets so I can manage different secrets for the same application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not natively supported, but you can create your own class derived from `OpenIddictApplicationManager<T>` and override `ValidateClientSecretAsync()` to support that.

That said, I'd recommend using the new client assertions feature introduced in OpenIddict 5.0. In this case, attaching multiple keys to the same application is supported.

See https://kevinchalet.com/2023/10/20/introducing-native-applications-per-client-token-lifetimes-and-client-assertions-support-in-openiddict-5-0-preview1/ for more information.